# Why does my istream_iterator not work?

Tags: c++, iterator, iostream, standard-library

Here is the code that I wrote. I am using Visual studio and learning how to use the standard template library. The `ostream_iterator` doesn't work either when I try to print from a source. It gives out a huge list of errors, those which I can't possibly understand.

This here is the *complete* code I am trying to run in Visual Studio. Can there be a problem in the software settings?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <iterator>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;
//stream_iterator
int main() {
    vector<string> source = { "31", "3113" };
    copy(istream_iterator<string>(cin), istream_iterator<string>(),back_inserter(source));  //can't understand why this won't work
    return 0;
}





These below are the error messages.
    1>------ Build started: Project: StreamIters, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
    1>  Source.cpp
    1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\iterator(256): error C2679: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
    1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(485): could be 'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator >>(std::basic_streambuf<char,std::char_traits<char>> *)'
    1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(466): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator >>(void *&)'
    1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(448): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator >>(long double &)'
    1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(430): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator >>(double &)'
    1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(411): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator >>(float &)'
    1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(392): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator >>(unsigned __int64 &)'
    1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(373): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator >>(__int64 &)'
    1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(353): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator >>(unsigned long &)'
    1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(335): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator >>(long &)'
    1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(317): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator >>(unsigned int &)'
    1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(291): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator >>(int &)'
    1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(272): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator >>(unsigned short &)'
    1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(237): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator >>(short &)'
    1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(218): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator >>(std::_Bool &)'
    1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(211): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator >>(std::ios_base &(__cdecl *)(std::ios_base &))'
    1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(204): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator >>(std::basic_ios<char,std::char_traits<char>> &(__cdecl *)(std::basic_ios<char,std::char_traits<char>> &))'
    1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(198): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator >>(std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &(__cdecl *)(std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &))'
    1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(1103): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::operator >><char,std::char_traits<char>,_Ty>(std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &&,_Ty &)'
    1>          with
    1>          [
    1>              _Ty=std::string
    1>          ]
    1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(1093): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::operator >><std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &,unsigned char &)'
    1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(1086): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::operator >><std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &,unsigned char *)'
    1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(1079): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::operator >><std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &,signed char &)'
    1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(1072): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::operator >><std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &,signed char *)'
    1>          while trying to match the argument list '(std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>, std::string)'
    1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\iterator(255) : while compiling class template member function 'void std::istream_iterator<std::string,char,std::char_traits<char>,ptrdiff_t>::_Getval(void)'
    1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\iterator(222) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::istream_iterator<std::string,char,std::char_traits<char>,ptrdiff_t>::_Getval(void)' being compiled
    1>          c:\users\mahe\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\streamiters\streamiters\source.cpp(19) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::istream_iterator<std::string,char,std::char_traits<char>,ptrdiff_t>' being compiled
    ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: [Can't replicate](http://ideone.com/y5ENMV). Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the *non-working* code and show us?

Comment: That code, as you've posted it, compiles without error with g++.  You might wish to `include <string>`.

Comment: Even if you personally don't understand the error message it's still a good idea to post all of it.

Comment: This is the complete code! Posted all parts of the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code lacks inclusion of the header `<string>`. While the interfaces used do require that at least a declaration of `std::string` is available, there is no requirement that the headers you included provide a definition of `std::string` and/or functions operating on them. I don't have MSVC++ installed but it seems the headers you included provide a definition of `std::string` but no declaration of the input or output operators.

As a rule of thumb you should never rely on indirect inclusion. Instead, you should always include all relevant headers explicitly: although the declarations may currently be available, headers may change to not include other headers.